# Gulp: Merging files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following project structure:

```
my_app
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── source
    └── locales
        ├ en
        │ ├─ core.json
        │ └─ ui.json
        ├ es
        │ ├─ core.json
        │ └─ ui.json
        ├ fr
        │ ├─ core.json
        │ └─ ui.json
        ├ ...
```

**Goal:** I want to merge the files in each language directory into one, ie.:

```
my_app
    ├── gulpfile.js
    ├── package.json
    └── source
        └── locales
            ├ en
            │ └─ strings.json
            ├ es
            │ └─ strings.json
            ├ fr
            │ └─ strings.json
            ├ ...
```

Here's my current gulp task that instead of doing that, merges ALL files:

```
var merge = require('gulp-merge-json');
...
gulp.src([
        'source/locales/**/*.json',
        'source/locales/**/*.json'
      ])
      .pipe(merge({fileName: 'strings.json'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('source/locales/'));
```

But that makes the directory structure like this:

```
my_app
    ├── gulpfile.js
    ├── package.json
    └── source
        └── locales
            └ strings.json
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by processing each locale folder into its own `gulp` task:

```
var fs    = require('fs'),
    path  = require('path'),
    gulp  = require('gulp'),
    merge = require('gulp-merge-json'),
    comb  = require('merge-stream');

function getLocales(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var locales = getLocales('source/locales');
  var tasks = locales.map(function(locale) {
    return gulp.src('source/locales/' + locale + '/*.json')
      .pipe(merge({fileName: 'strings.json'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('source/locales/' + locale));
  });

  return comb(tasks);
});
```